# unity c# touch coordinates

Tags: touch, coordinates, unity-game-engine

hi I'm working on a simple game project and I want to instantiate a gameobject from the position i touch on screen I wrote the following the code but the coordinates doesn't match. it instantiate the object but i cant see where it is on screen I think there is something i miss to fix this and I don't know how here is the code:

```
if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {   

            Debug.Log("touch begun" + Input.GetTouch(0).position);
            Vector3 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            Instantiate(bulletPrefab, Input.GetTouch(0).position, Quaternion.identity);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of Input.GetTouch(0).position is in pixel coordinates of the screen.
The instantiation of an object is in world space coordinates.
You should get the screen corner coordinates in world space and offset x and y from there with the touch values.

Try this out:

```
        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            Vector3 touchData = Input.GetTouch(0).position;

            touchData.x = x;
            touchData.y = y;
            // Construct a ray from the current touch coordinates
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector2(touchData.x, touchData.y));
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray))
            {
                float desiredValueForZ = 2f; //this depends on your project stuff, I don't know.
                Instantiate(bulletPrefab, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(touchData.x, touchData.y, desiredValueForZ)), transform.rotation);
            }
        }
```